# publish 2 apk on Google Play. One for tablet, and the other for smartphone

Tags: android, google-play, apk, tablet, device

I'd like to publish my game on Google Play.

I've made two versions of the game. One for tablet and one for smartphone.
Do you know how I can distinguish the two of them on my Google Play dev account ?

For the moment, if I upload the apk for tablets, it says 4178 devices compatible. In them, tablets AND smartphone.

Do I have to manually enter every smartphone in excluded devices ? Or is there a way to automatically choose only tablets devices ?

Thank you for your answers,

Comment: Simple , in application title add (mobile),(tablet) words.

Comment: ? Are you sure ? So if my game is named "The game", I put "The game Tablet", in will automatically be for tablet in Google Play ?

Comment: Nah...but atleast the user who is downloading can see the title and choose the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest you can use the `<supports-screens />` to distinguish between tablets and smartphones.